# Using Square's Retrofit Client, is it possible to cancel an in progress request? If so how?

Tags: java, android, networking, retrofit

I'm using Square's Retrofit Client to make short-lived json requests from an Android App. Is there a way to cancel a request? If so, how?

Comment: any update on that? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately no, although I did just file this [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/319)

Comment: yeah i found that after, looks like it's in their plans...

Answer (score 22):

For canceling async **Retrofit** request, you can achieve it by shutting down the [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) that performs the async request.

For example I had this code to build the `RestAdapter`:

```
Builder restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder();
restAdapter.setEndpoint(BASE_URL);
restAdapter.setClient(okClient);
restAdapter.setErrorHandler(mErrorHandler);
mExecutorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
restAdapter.setExecutors(mExecutor, new MainThreadExecutor());
restAdapter.setConverter(new GsonConverter(gb.create()));
```

and had this method for forcefully abandoning the requests:

```
public void stopAll(){
   List<Runnable> pendingAndOngoing = mExecutorService.shutdownNow();
   // probably await for termination.
}
```

Alternatively you could make use of `ExecutorCompletionService` and either `poll(timeout, TimeUnit.MILISECONDS)` or `take()` all ongoing tasks. This will prevent thread pool not being shut down, as it would do with `shutdownNow()` and so you could reuse your `ExecutorService`

Hope it would be of help for someone.

**Edit**: As of OkHttp 2 [RC1](http://publicobject.com/2014/05/24/okhttp-2-0-rc1/) [changelog](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) performing a `.cancel(Object tag)` is possible. We should expect the same feature in upcoming Retrofit:

You can use actual `Request` object to cancel it

`okClient.cancel(request);`

or if you have supplied tag to `Request.Builder` you have to use

`okClient.cancel(request.tag());`

All ongoing, executed or pending requests are queued inside `Dispatcher`, `okClient.getDispatcher()`. You can call cancel method on this object too. Cancel method will notify OkHttp `Engine` to kill the connection to the host, if already established.

**Edit 2**: Retrofit 2 has fully featured canceling requests.

Comment: On which thread does the `shutdownNode` have to be executed? Because currently I perform it on the UI thread and the request/transmission is not canceled at all.

Comment: Have you also tried to await termination after calling shutdownNow()?

Comment: No, but what difference should this make?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski how to use Request.Builder in retrofit

Comment: Can you put example code that's working? I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

> Wrap the callback in a delegate object that implements Callback as
>   well. Call some method to clear out the delegate and have it just
>   no-op whenever it gets a response.

Look at the following discussion

https://plus.google.com/107765816683139331166/posts/CBUQgzWzQjS

Better strategy would be canceling the callback execution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271559/1446469

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented cancelable callback class based on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271559/5227676

```
public abstract class CancelableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private static List<CancelableCallback> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean isCanceled = false;
    private Object mTag = null;

    public static void cancelAll() {
        Iterator<CancelableCallback> iterator = mList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator.next().isCanceled = true;
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    public static void cancel(Object tag) {
        if (tag != null) {
            Iterator<CancelableCallback> iterator = mList.iterator();
            CancelableCallback item;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                item = iterator.next();
                if (tag.equals(item.mTag)) {
                    item.isCanceled = true;
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public CancelableCallback() {
        mList.add(this);
    }

    public CancelableCallback(Object tag) {
        mTag = tag;
        mList.add(this);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        isCanceled = true;
        mList.remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void success(T t, Response response) {
        if (!isCanceled)
            onSuccess(t, response);
        mList.remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        if (!isCanceled)
            onFailure(error);
        mList.remove(this);
    }

    public abstract void onSuccess(T t, Response response);

    public abstract void onFailure(RetrofitError error);
}
```

Usage example

```
rest.request(..., new CancelableCallback<MyResponse>(TAG) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(MyResponse myResponse, Response response) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {
       ...
    }
});

// if u need to cancel all
CancelableCallback.cancelAll();
// or cancel by tag
CancelableCallback.cancel(TAG);
```

Comment: Nice solution but your cancelAll and cancel(ObjectTag) will java.util.ConcurrentModificationException as you remove object from list without itrator. Iterate the list using iterator.

Answer (score 2):

This is for retrofit 2.0, the method **call.cancel()** is there which cancels the in-flight call as well. below is the document definition for it.

```
retrofit2.Call

public abstract void cancel()
```

*Cancel this call. An attempt will be made to cancel in-flight calls, and if the call has not yet been executed it never will be.*

Answer (score 1):

Now there is an easy way in latest version of Retrofit V 2.0.0.beta2. Can implement retry too.
Take a look here [How to cancel ongoing request in retrofit when retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient is used as client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30479788/how-to-cancel-ongoing-request-in-retrofit-when-retrofit-client-urlconnectionclie)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Retrofit 2.0 beta 3 changelog via link https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases/tag/parent-2.0.0-beta3

> New: isCanceled() method returns whether a Call has been canceled. Use this in onFailure to determine whether the callback was invoked from cancelation or actual transport failure.

This should make stuff easier.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late, but I've possibly found a solution.
I haven't been able to prevent a request from being executed, but if you're satisfied with the request being performed and not doing anything, you might check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269806/perform-requests-with-retrofit-inside-custom-runnable) question and answer, both made by me.