# Perform requests with Retrofit inside custom Runnable

Tags: android, threadpoolexecutor, retrofit

I am migrating from `Volley` to a custom implementation using `Retrofit`, but I'm trying to add to my implementation some of the `Volley` features that I liked, for example

**RequestQueue.cancel(String tag)**

If the `Request` has the requested tag, then it's canceled by setting a `boolean` value, `mCanceled`, to true. The `run` method checks this value and returns if it's true.
To be able to reproduce this with `Retrofit` I should be able to use my custom class implementing `Runnable` instead of the default one, where I have a `mTag` and a `mCanceled` field. 
Moreover, `Volley` was also able to set such flag inside the active `Thread`s and immediately stop them. My `cancelAll` method, that I've already implemented, just drains the queue to another queue, but isn't able to access the active threads.
Is it possible to achieve the same results with `Retrofit` and `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think I've found a nicer solution: instead of blocking the `Runnable` of the requests, I am blocking the `Callback` execution.

I have extended the `Callback` interface:

```
public interface CustomCallbackInterface<T> extends Callback<T> {
    public String getTag();
    public String setTag(String tag);
    public void cancel();
    public boolean isCanceled();
}
```

so that each `Callback` has a tag and a cancel flag. Then the `success` method starts with:

```
public class CustomCallback<ConvertedData> implements CustomCallbackInterface<ConvertedData>{

    //failure...

    @Override
    public void success(ConvertedData cd, Response response) {
        if(isCanceled()) return;
        // ....
    }
}
```

Every time I make a new request, I store the created `CustomCallback` inside a `List` cancel just iterates the list and calls `cancel()` on the items with the same tag.

Comment: Can you add a little more code please? Like the request call

Comment: @letroll you make the request as a normal one, but instead of using `new Callback` you do `Callback cb = new Callback` so you have a reference and can then call `callbacks.add(cb)`

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think you're returning **after** the request got its response (in your code: successfully). YOu're not actually cancelling the request in mid air :) But I might be wrong.

Comment: @feresr Yes, until retrofit 2.0 there will be no way to cancel any in progress request, but this way the response will be just ignored.

Comment: also @feresr he is returning <b>after</b> the request got its response but he is doing <b>nothing</b> when its succeeded which means the request in effect got cancelled, which I also believe is the best way as there is no way to cancel requests in retrofit by itself

Comment: This nicer solution will not help when you want to interrupt an up/download request. The files gets transfered but the user not notified

Comment: @MartinVonMartinsgrün I know, it is a workaround. The request will be ignored. That's all.

Answer (score 11):

I've implemented an easy to use class based on Vektor88 answer

```
public abstract class CancelableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private static List<CancelableCallback> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    private boolean isCanceled = false;
    private Object mTag = null;

    public static void cancelAll() {
        Iterator<CancelableCallback> iterator = mList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator.next().isCanceled = true;
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    public static void cancel(Object tag) {
        if (tag != null) {
            Iterator<CancelableCallback> iterator = mList.iterator();
            CancelableCallback item;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                item = iterator.next();
                if (tag.equals(item.mTag)) {
                    item.isCanceled = true;
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public CancelableCallback() {
        mList.add(this);
    }

    public CancelableCallback(Object tag) {
        mTag = tag;
        mList.add(this);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        isCanceled = true;
        mList.remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void success(T t, Response response) {
        if (!isCanceled)
            onSuccess(t, response);
        mList.remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        if (!isCanceled)
            onFailure(error);
        mList.remove(this);
    }

    public abstract void onSuccess(T t, Response response);

    public abstract void onFailure(RetrofitError error);
}
```

Usage example

```
rest.request(..., new CancelableCallback<MyResponse>(TAG) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(MyResponse myResponse, Response response) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {
       ...
    }
});

// if u need to cancel all
CancelableCallback.cancelAll();
// or cancel by tag
CancelableCallback.cancel(TAG);
```