# Commit fragment in onResume leads to IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is a list fragment with a list of ID's. By clicking on a ID a new activity DETAIL_ACTIVITY starts and loads data by ID from a rest service. This loading happens in the onResume method of DETAIL_ACTIVITY. When loading has finished the fetched data is used to show a fragment. Like so:

```
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();

  fetchById(new Callback(){
      public void success(Item someData){
          SomeFragment fragment = ...
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                     .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                                     .commit();
      }
  });
}
```

This works most of the time. However when internet connection is slow and I move back from DETAIL_ACTIVITY when it has not finished loading yet, it will throw following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
>               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)

using

```
commitAllowingStateLoss()
```

does not fix this error. Any other ideas on this?

Comment: Are you certain that this is the line of code (FragmentTransaction) that is responsible for the IllegalStateException?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if we fix the issue, next you will face a new exception **"Activity has been destroyed"**, since you have moved back from the activity. Here is the piece of code which throws this exception.

```
    private void checkStateLoss() {
        if (mStateSaved) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
        }
        if (mNoTransactionsBecause != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Can not perform this action inside of " + mNoTransactionsBecause);
        }
    }

    public void enqueueAction(Runnable action, boolean allowStateLoss) {
        if (!allowStateLoss) {
            checkStateLoss();
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mDestroyed || mActivity == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Activity has been destroyed");
            }
        ...
     }
```

**The correct fix for this would be, stop the thread which is downloading the data in `Activity`'s [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) method, as you have started it in [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) method.**

From [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html):

> For example, if your activity has a thread running in the background
>   to download data from the network, it might create that thread in
>   onCreate() and then stop the thread in onDestroy().

Cancel running retrofit is not include in the library at the moment. For all searching for a solution see

- [Perform requests with Retrofit inside custom Runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23269806/perform-requests-with-retrofit-inside-custom-runnable/23271559#23271559)
- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297

Comment: +1 thanks for this comprehensive info. I am using retrofit library for REST operations. I am not sure how to cancel such thread.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you've already solved your problem. But if not:

Fragment is not guaranteed to resume on `FragmentActivity.onResume()`. As according to Android developer documentation, you should do so in `FragmentActivity.onResumeFragment()` instead. See:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResume()

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. I haven't even knew about this method existence.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried not calling the super method in the `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    // No call to super.onSaveInstanceState
}
```

Comment: i think it will throw an exception: SuperNotCalledException

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use Handler to redirect you result of the Thread and after than add Fragment this. Because thread is running in memory separate process. So please use handler