# How to cancel ongoing request in retrofit when retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient is used as client?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit for http calls in my Android application and retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient as the client while building the adapter.

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(
                    new Client.Provider() {
                        public Client get() {
                            return new UrlConnectionClient() {
                                @Override
                                protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Request request)
                                        throws IOException {
                                    HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(request);
                                    connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
                                    return connection;
                                }
```

I wanted to set the timeout so I have used UrlConnectionClient as my client. I could not find a way with other clients like OkHttp.

Question is : How can I cancel the ongoing request ?.

I have seen a similar post @ [Using Square's Retrofit Client, is it possible to cancel an in progress request? If so how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131382/using-squares-retrofit-client-is-it-possible-to-cancel-an-in-progress-request)   but my code would get really complex if I try to add my own executors and try to cancel the request using that. I am looking if there is slightly a better way with my existing code.

I also see that Retorofit V2.0 has plan for Retry and Cancel but not sure when that would be released..https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297

Need help !
In fact I also need a way to retry with the same code.

Comment: The owner of retrofit told me that he would get retry and cancel feature in around a month though not promised. Currently there is no way it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been available since 2.0.0-beta2 (https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases/tag/parent-2.0.0-beta2). I don't know if there is a doc that explains that but here is the link to API:
http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit/Call.html#cancel--

'Call' API allows to do Retry as well by 'Clone'ing the request.

Comment: The second link is dead.

Comment: Retrofit 2.x: http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit/Call.html#cancel--

Comment: Yes, seems not working at the moment. Not sure if it can resume later. Bu this works : https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/  and on left side click on the class you would like to see the javadoc for.