# Android async callback. When exit from UI app crashes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, callback, retrofit

I have a fragment with RecyclerView, on RecyclerView I have custom items with Button, on click I send request with Callback.
I'm using retrofit2 library for API on backend server.

Problem appears when I send request and exit from UI, of course app crashes because on post execute for this request I update UI, and this UI does not exist.

How can I solve this problem?

I see two ways, on destoy method in my view try to stop with request, or on postexecute check if UI does not exist.

What will be better?

If it's first way, how I can do it ?

Request example:

```
private void getStoreStatus() {
    Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(APIURL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    mRestApi = restAdapter.create(IHansaAPI.class);

    mRestApi.getStatusStore(mStoreId).enqueue(new Callback<HansaCrawlerResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<HansaCrawlerResponse> response) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.body().getResponse().getMessage() + " " + response.body().getResponse().getCode() + " " + mCurrentStore.getId());

            switch (response.body().getResponse().getMessage()) {

                case NOT_FOUND:
                    mCurrentStore.setmStatusRegistration(0);
                    setmCurrentStatus(0, mCurrentStore.getIsClosed());
                    break;
                case IN_BASE:
                    mCurrentStore.setmStatusRegistration(2);
                    setmCurrentStatus(2, mCurrentStore.getIsClosed());
                    break;
                case PROCESSIND:
                    mCurrentStore.setmStatusRegistration(1);
                    setmCurrentStatus(1, mCurrentStore.getIsClosed());
                    break;
                default:
                    mCurrentStore.setmStatusRegistration(-1);
                    setmCurrentStatus(-1, mCurrentStore.getIsClosed());
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error get Status");
        }
    });
}
```

Sorry for my English :(

Comment: Check this link, you will get your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131382/using-squares-retrofit-client-is-it-possible-to-cancel-an-in-progress-request

Answer (score 0):

Do not update UI from background thread, and check if Activity is not finishing only than update UI.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!isFinishing()) {

            /*Update Your UI here. this way you can check if your Activity is live than can update UI. cancel network request in onDestroy will also help. */

      }
        }
    });
```